# How can I load .class files from one project(project 2) to another web project(Project 3) at dynamically runtime in java?

Tags: java

I have Three Java  projects.

1. Project1  is for creating library and produces one jar file.
2. Project2  will execute based on jar which is produced by Project1.
3. Project3 is web application(Servlets and JSP) , Project3 is also using jar file which is produced by Project1 and  ***I need to load .class files of Project2 in Project3 at dynamically  Runtime.***

Project3  also need use jar file which is produced by Project1.

I run these applications in Tomcat and JBOSS servers, when I go to browser and run these aaplications, I am getting web page but I am not getting data. It is saying ClassNotFound Exception, means I failed to load classes dynamically at Runtime.

Please help me can I avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat you can deploy the web application exploded, instead of deploying it as a war file. Deploy it expanded and add the missing class. If the missing class is the jar created by Project 1 then you'd know there's a dependency missing (assuming you are using maven). If the missing class is from project 2 then you know you have a missing library (assuming all classes from Project 2 are pre-defined).

If this doesn't help then modify your post and add the classes you have deployed to Tomcat and  the full message on which class could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

put all jar files you work on at WEB-INF/lib at tomcat deployment folder
they will be usable by your code.

Comment: Thank you for response.I already put all jar files at WEB-INF/lib,but same issue.

Comment: if all your classes are in Jar files, and by any chance there is a classes folder inside WEB-INF/lib, Delete it. it may contains some package names similar to other packages in jar files, but with missing classes, this might create an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do something quite similar to what you're doing in a project of mine. I have a library that defines an API (one Eclipse project) that's used by another library (the implementation of that API, a separate Eclipse project) and a WAR file (the consumer of the API, and — you guessed it — a third Eclipse project).

I do it by using a Mavenized build system. If you've not used Maven before, it's a major step up in terms of build capabilities over what you're used to. To make everything work, I just state (in the Project Object Model file for the implementation) that the API module is a dependency of the implementation, and (in the Project Object Model file for the WAR) that both API and implementation modules are dependencies of the WAR. Maven then builds everything for me, putting the JARs of the API and implementation in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the WAR.

Because going to Maven is a *huge* step, you might be best off just putting the relevant JAR files in the `WEB-INF/lib` yourself. Maybe you need to tell your IDE more clearly about the dependencies so it can put the files there for you? Or maybe you can put them there by hand.

Comment: It's possible to use custom classloaders to do other ways of doing the loading. ***DON'T DO THAT!*** It's very confusing and *very* hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Maven & Artifact` for build management. It will take care about all these kind of dependencies.
Refer it from its [official site](http://maven.apache.org/).